# How to render HTML value e.g "<div><div>Go to Google</div><div>Search on spfx react project</div></div>", in SPFX project using type script?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, react

We have created spfx react project for SharePoint online using type script:

Here, props.appendTextDetails value is "Go to GoogleSearch on spfx react project".

const FCRichtext = (props:any) => {

```
return <div>
  <Label>{props.appendTextDetails}</Label>
</div>
```

};
export default FCRichtext;

How can we render the HTML value?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` attribute to add the HTML.

Modify your code as below:

```
return <div>
  <Label><div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={props.appendTextDetails} /></Label>
</div>
```

[React DOM elements](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Answer (score 0):

You can use React render html package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-render-html

```
import renderHTML from 'react-render-html';

render() {
return (
  <div className='sample'>
    {renderHTML(someHTML)}
  </div>
);
```

}